# I would like to find if the new found links from Beautiful soup is already in the queue.txt file and crawled.txt file

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup, python-requests, duplicates

I have a beautiful soup program where I find all the links on a webpage and put it in a queue.txt file. The program then gets each link from the file and find all the links on those links. They then get put into a crawled.txt file for all the crawled links.

I want to make sure I get no duplicates so I want the program to go through the queue.txt and crawled.txt and if the links that have just been found are in those files, then the new found links shouldn't be put in the file

I have tried doing it so that it prints the newly found links into a list and removes duplicates from there and prints the list to a .txt file but it wouldn't be able to tell what is in the queue file it only removes duplicates from the newly found links from the one page.

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def get_links(base_url, file_name):
    page = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    single_slash = re.compile(r'^/\w')
    double_slash = re.compile(r'^//\w')

    parsed_uri = urlparse(base_url)
    domain_name = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=parsed_uri)

    with open(file_name, "a") as f:
        for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
            link = str(tag.get('href'))

            if str(link).startswith("http"):
                link = link
                print(link)

            if double_slash.match(link):
                link = 'https:' + link
                print(link)

            if single_slash.match(link):
                link = domain_name + link
                print(link)

            if str(link).startswith("#"):
                continue

            if str(link).startswith("j"):
                continue

            if str(link).startswith('q'):
                continue

            if str(link).startswith('u'):
                continue

            if str(link).startswith('N'):
                continue

            if str(link).startswith('m'):
                continue

            try:
                f.write(link + '\n')
            except:
                pass

get_links('https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-lists-to-a-file-in-python/', "queue.txt")

with open('queue.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
print(lines)

for link in lines:

    if lines[0] == "/":
        del lines[0]

    print(lines[0])
    with open('crawled.txt', 'a') as h:
        h.write('%s\n' % lines[0])
        h.close()

    del lines[0]

    if lines[0] == "/":
        del lines[0]

    with open('queue.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
        for listitem in lines:
            filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)

        page_url = lines[0]
        get_links(page_url, "queue.txt")
    print(lines)

    with open('queue.txt') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general for Python, when trying to remove duplicates, sets are usually a good bet. For example:

```
lines = open('queue.txt', 'r').readlines()
queue_set = set(lines)
result = open('queue.txt', 'w')
for line in queue_set:
    result.write(line)
```

Note: This will not preserve the order of the links, but I don't see a reason for that in this case.
Also, this was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15830595/13940026).