# How can I append one text file to another in Python, if there might be overlap between the two?

Tags: python, datetime, merge

Say I have two .txt files. The first one is:

```
2024-01-26 09:00:00, Alice, 4, Win
2024-01-27 09:00:00, Bob, 6, Loss
2024-01-28 09:00:00, Charlie, 2, Loss
2024-01-29 09:00:00, Denise, 3, Loss
```

The second one is:

```
2024-01-29 09:00:00, Denise, 3, Loss
2024-01-30 09:00:00, Eve, 3, Win
2024-01-31 09:00:00, Frank, 15, Win
```

How can I merge into this?

```
2024-01-26 09:00:00, Alice, 4, Win
2024-01-27 09:00:00, Bob, 6, Loss
2024-01-28 09:00:00, Charlie, 2, Loss
2024-01-29 09:00:00, Denise, 3, Loss
2024-01-30 09:00:00, Eve, 3, Win
2024-01-31 09:00:00, Frank, 15, Win
```

I know of my data:

- Both files have their data in chronological order
- It's possible there will be overlap, in which case the two text files should have exactly the same data, and I want to delete the overlap
- The files are very big, so efficiency matters
- Order is important; I want the output in chronological order

(Basically, it's like taking two chunks of data from the same Jan-Dec dataset, say Jan-Mar and Mar-Jun, and then merging them back into a Jan-Jun block. No guarantees there'll actually be an overlap as well, e.g. if one block is Jan-Mar and the other is Jun-Aug.)

Things I've considered/tried ...

- It's easy enough to directly append the two files. I could conceivably append them and then delete duplicate lines. However deleting duplicate lines does not look quick, since the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830290/remove-duplicates-from-text-file) would search through the entire file even though I know the duplication only occurs in the middle (at the end of the first file and the start of the second file).
- Because the order is important, `set` does not work well to detect overlaps. I could conceivably use it anyway and then sort the output before saving, but destroying the order before reassembling it also looks inefficient.
- The human way to do this would be to take the last line of the first file and see if it's before the first line of the second file; if yes then there's no problem with direct merging, while if no I would skip until I find the first line in the second file that's after that date. But this looks complicated, because I'd have to extract the last line first, convert all the text before the first comma into date/time, and compare the two. (With more `while` loops afterwards.)
- Bing suggested I use `shutil.copyfileobj`, but that appears to just append one file into the other without looking for overlaps.

Is there a better way to do this? I'm actually kind of shocked I've not been able to Google for an answer to this, because it seems like it should be a common problem.

Comment: Your 'human way' can be coded. You can (very quickly) seek to the last line of file1, read the last line, then read lines from file2, compare with the stored `lastline` and append file2 from the non-overlap point. You can search how to do each of these things in Python.

Comment: @user19077881 Indeed, after some struggling, I got it to work. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a generic answer which works you could consider answering your own question to make the code available for anyone who has the same need. SO is intended as searchable resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def appendData(file1Path, file2Path):

    with open(file1Path, 'r') as file1:
        lines1 = list(line.strip() for line in file1)

    with open(file2Path, 'r') as file2:
        lines2 = list(line.strip() for line in file2)

    res = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lines1 + lines2))

    with open(file1Path, 'w') as resultFile:
        resultFile.write('\n'.join(res))

# replace with your file paths
file1Path = '1.txt'
file2Path = '2.txt'

appendData(file1Path, file2Path)
```

The above code will store the result in 1.txt, if you want to store the result in a separate file you can pass the path of the result file as one more argument.

Comment: This works (+1), but it's slow =/ I imagine the reason is the line ````res = lines1 + [line for line in lines2 if line not in lines1]```` does not make use of the fact that the program doesn't have to check every line, it only needs to check from the end of lines1 until the time it uses is reached.

Comment: @Allure I've updated the solution, please have a look

Comment: There are several ways to (very quickly) read the last line from a file without going through the whole (perhaps millions of lines). See for example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258499/how-to-read-the-last-line-of-a-file-in-python). Reading two files into memory and using a Dictionary to remove duplicates is not efficient for very large files.

Comment: Coding the "human way" turned out to be doable, resulting in fundamentally different code, and is much faster as well. I'm accepting your answer anyway. Thanks for trying!